# View Datagridview in Print Preview Window

Tags: visual-studio-2010, datagridview, vb.net-2010, printdocument, print-preview

I am creating an application in vb.net. I have a datagridview control in my VB form. I need to view it on printpreview window with the contents in it. I have other control like labels and textboxes in the form and I can view all in printpreview. In the case of Datagridview control, I have a working printpreview code which I got from net. My problem is, I need to change the x and y positions of datagridview control. With the following code, the datagridview control is displaying over the other controls. I dont know how to do it in this code. Please help me. 
I need to change the x and y positions of DataGridView like given in the below code(50 and 225).
 e.Graphics.DrawString(Label7.Text, Label7.Font, Brushes.Black, 50, 225)

The code I used to display gridview is given below.

Code :

---

Dim ColumnCount As Integer = DataGridView1.ColumnCount
        Dim RowCount As Integer = DataGridView1.RowCount

```
    Dim CellTopPos As Integer = PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top

    For Row = 0 To RowCount - 2

        Dim CellLeftPos As Integer = PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left

        For Cell = 0 To ColumnCount - 1

            Dim CellValue As String = DataGridView1.Rows(Row).Cells(Cell).Value.ToString()
            Dim CellWidth = DataGridView1.Rows(Row).Cells(Cell).Size.Width + 10
            Dim CellHeight = DataGridView1.Rows(Row).Cells(Cell).Size.Height

            Dim Brush As New SolidBrush(Color.Black)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(CellValue, New Font("arial", 9), Brush, CellLeftPos, CellTopPos)
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, CellLeftPos, CellTopPos, CellWidth, CellHeight)

            CellLeftPos += CellWidth
        Next

        CellTopPos += DataGridView1.Rows(Row).Cells(0).Size.Height
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this class .. unfortunately there is characters limit so i can not able to post code
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18042/Another-DataGridView-Printer

Comment: Thanks... If I use this code, can I specify the position of datagridview control in print preview window?

Comment: I have found the solution by myself, I have set 240(top) and -45(left) as the position of datagridview.  
code :
Dim CellTopPos As Integer = PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top + 240

        For Row = 0 To RowCount - 2                        
Dim CellLeftPos As Integer = PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left - 45
-----------------------------------------
Anyway, thanks to Imran Ali Khan for his time...